# how to update id as row number in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a table did not contains id, now I add the id column and want to update the id as row number, what should I do? this is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `spark_car_brand` (
  `alpha` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am using this SQL seems did not work:

```
update spark_car_brand
set id = ROW_NUMBER();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `id` column to `AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL` it will again a unique identifier. `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns need to be part of a primary or unique key and since you don't have one, this is recommended:

```
alter table spark_car_brand
modify id int not null auto_increment primary key;
```

Comment: I did not know it will auto generate the id number. thank you! it works.@danblack

Comment: I had to test it myself to be sure.

Comment: @Dolphin - If you were previously generating your own number, you should now get rid of that code.